# Строка высотой с блок максимальной высоты в этой строке

Tags: html, css, список

http://jsfiddle.net/RC8vX/

Необходимо, чтобы строка была высотой с блок максимальной высоты в этой строке (количество элементов в строке не фиксировано)

Answer (score 1):

Если задача стоит именно так, как вы сформулировали, то только скриптом обходить весь список и смотреть, в какой строке какая высота у какого блока, вычислять и назначать.

Если же нужно всего лишь выравнять блоки, то вам подойдёт например такой вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/RC8vX/5/

Другой вариант, также имеющий право на существование: http://jsfiddle.net/RC8vX/6/

Comment: кстати, оборачивать каждые два li в div — это, мягко говоря, не самое лучшее решение :) В списке могут быть только элементы списка, такие правила всё же лучше не нарушать. Некоторые браузеры могут отказаться понимать такую разметку, и будут правы.